# use GPU/TPL on C# code to speed up things, taking 40 minutes

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I want to perform some calculations on a text file that have 1 number *"0,1"* on each line and have almost **1 million** lines.

What I want to check how many time a sequence exists in the whole file and it makes a sequence according to the `sequence length`is, for example my file is:

> 01100101011....up to 1 milion (each number on a new line)

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
        time.Start();
        try
        {
            // I have hard coded fileName and Sequence Length that i am taking from user
            string data = "", fileName = "10.txt";  // this file has almost 1 Million records
            int first = 0, last = 0;
            
            // reads data and make a string of that data
            // which means "data" = "1001011001010100101 .... upto 1 million"
            data = string.Join("", File.ReadAllLines(fileName)); 
            last = Convert.ToInt32("15"); // sequence length
            int l = data.Length;    // calculates it one time so that dont have to do it everytime
            
            //so why i create List is because sometime Array dont get fully used to its length
            // and get Null values at the end
            List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
            while (first + last < l+1)
            {
                dataList.Add((data.Substring(first, last)));
                first++;
            }
            // converts list to Array so array will have values and no Null
            // and will use Array.FindAll() later
            string[] dataArray = dataList.ToArray(), value;
            
            // get rready a file to start writing on
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "Results.txt");
            
            //THIS IS THE PART THATS TAKING around 40 minutes
            for (int j = 0; j < dataArray.Length; j++)
            {
                // finds a value in whole array and make array of that finding 
                value = Array.FindAll(dataArray, str => str.Equals(dataArray[j]));
                // value.Length means the count of the Number in the whole array
                sw.WriteLine(value.Length);
            }
            sw.Close();
            time.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time : " + time.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception " + ex.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I set a `sequence length = 3`, now what my program does make an array :

> dataArray = {"011" , "110" , "100" , "001" , "010" , "101" , "011"}

by making use of `String.Substring()` . Now I simply want to calculate the **Frequency** of element of the array.

**Data in Resultant .txt file**

> 011 - 2
>
> 110 - 0
>
> 100 - 0
>
> 001 - 0
>
> 010 - 0
>
> 101 - 0
>
> 011 - 2

Now it seems to be pretty simple but it is not, I can't convert it `int` because it's a sequence I don't want to lost the zeros at the front of the sequence.

Right now my program has to loop **1 million (each element ) X 1 million (compares with each element of array) = 1 trillion** times. It is taking almost 40 minutes. I want to know how can I make it fast , *Parallel.For, TPL* I don't know about them how to use them. Because it should be done in seconds.

**My Systems Specs**

> 32 GB RAM
>
> i7- 5820k 3.30 ghz
>
> 64 bit
>
> 2x nvidia gtx 970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your code and question correctly, you need to "slide a window" (of length N, `last` in your original code) over the text, and count how many times each substring exists in the text.

If that's right, the following code does it in 0.292 seconds or thereabouts on a million-character file, and you don't need parallelism or GPU at all.

The idea here is to tally the chunk counts into a `Dictionary` as we're sliding that window over the text.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> CountChunks(string data, int chunkLength)
    {
        var chunkCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var l = data.Length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l - chunkLength; i++)
        {
            var chunk = data.Substring(i, chunkLength);
            int count = 0;
            chunkCounts.TryGetValue(chunk, out count);
            chunkCounts[chunk] = count + 1;
        }
        return chunkCounts;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var time = new Stopwatch();
        time.Start();
        var fileName = "10.txt";
        var data = string.Join("", File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        var chunkCounts = CountChunks(data, 15);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "Results.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var pair in chunkCounts)
            {
                sw.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} - {pair.Value}");
            }
        }
        time.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time : " + time.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

The output `10Results.txt` looks something like

```
011100000111100 - 34
111000001111000 - 37
110000011110001 - 27
100000111100010 - 28
000001111000101 - 37
000011110001010 - 36
000111100010100 - 44
001111000101001 - 35
011110001010011 - 41
111100010100110 - 42
```

etc.

*EDIT:* Here's the equivalent Python program. It's a little slower at about 0.9 seconds.

```py
import time
from collections import Counter

t0 = time.time()
c = Counter()
data = ''.join(l for l in open('10.txt'))
l = 15
for i in range(0, len(data) - l):
    c[data[i : i + l]] += 1

with open('10Results2.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for key, value in c.items():
        print(f'{key} - {value}', file=outf)

print(time.time() - t0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop will give you terrible performance as it has to loop through a million string comparison.
I would suggest using a dictionary instead of a list to store your sequence as a key and count as a value.
It should give you much better performance as compared to a while/for loop .
All you need to do is tweak a little bit for performance point of view and may not even need to leverage GPU/TLP runtime unless it's you sole purpose. 
Something below should get you going.

```
       string keyString = string.Empty;
       Dictionary<string,int> dataList = new Dictionary<string,int>;
        while (first + last < l+1)
        {
            keyString = data.Substring(first, last);
            if(dataList.ContainsKey(keyString)
               {
                 dataList[keyString] = dataList[keyString] + 1; 
               }
             else
               {
                 dataList.Add(keyString,1);
               }
            first++;
        }
```

the rest of the code you need is to print this dictionary.